# Cron with beautifulsoup not running

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, cron

Python file runs properly when executed from terminal.

Gives error "ImportError: No module named bs4" when run with cron.

I'm running python3.6 from /anaconda3/lib/python3.6

```
python3.6
>>> from crontab import CronTab
>>> cron = CronTab(user=True)
>>> job = cron.new(command='python /Users/X/Y/Z/Hello.py')
>>> job.minute.every(1)
>>> cron.write()
```

Hello.py calls beautifulsoup from bs4, which is in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/

Cron details are:

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
```

Comment: How many versions of python have you got installed? Have you tried putting the full path to the python executable in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` path to `sys.path` before importing `bs4`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
```

**OR**

Add `PYTHONPATH` to crontab environment:

```
$ sudo crontab -e

PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

Comment: @the_it_crowd are you sure bs4 package is installed in `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`? Did you import bs4 **after** you added path to `sys.path`? It should work. Try to print `sys.path` when you run the script from terminal and compare it when you run it from cron.

Comment: Thanks @Andrej Kesely. Cron and terminal were using different sys.paths - once I fixed those, it worked!